# App not installed after trying to install the new version from bitbucket pipelines

Tags: android, installation, azure-pipelines, build.gradle, apk

The scenario:
I have installed the apk in my physical device.
I build a new version of the apk on bitbucket with the pipelines.
I download the apk after a successful build and try to install to the same physical device.
I get App not install. (if i delete the old version then the new one can be installed)

I read somewhere that i need to change the versionCode and versionName to the build.gradle, which I did but the same thing happened.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try `adb install -r [APK]`

Comment: @Jesse thank you for the asnwer! i want to install an apk that is built and downloaded from the pipelines and not from the studio. any suggestions ?

Comment: The versioncode needs to be higher than the version code of the previously installed app. They both need to be signed with the same signing key. This means, that usually you can't install a release version over a debug version unless you configured the signig keys to match.

Comment: The versionCode is higher than the previous one! and right now i am trying to install from the bitbucket pipeline build on debug version! The previous one is the same thing, the same code but different versionCodes and VersionName (higher)